# Proof $x \in \overline{M}$ iff there is a sequence $(x_n)$ with $x_n \to x$ for $n \to \infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, analysis, proof-writing

Let $M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$

How can one prove that $x \in \overline{M}$ iff there is a sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $x_n \to x$ for $n \to \infty$?

Tbh, I don't understand the relationship between $\overline{M}$ and $x_n$.
Can someone explain that?

Comment: Did you mean to also require $x_n\in M$ for your sequence $(x_n)$?

Comment: A lot depends on how you define $\overline M$.

Comment: @UmbertoP. It's the closure

Comment: There are many equivalent definitions of closure. What is yours?

Comment: @UmbertoP. $M \cup \partial M$

Comment: You're getting there. What is your definition of $\partial M$?

Comment: @UmbertoP. ${\displaystyle \{x\in X\ |\ \forall U\in {\mathfrak {U}}(x):U\cap M\neq \emptyset \wedge U\cap M^{C}\neq \emptyset \}}$ with $M \subseteq X$ being a subset of a topological space

Comment: OK. What does that mean in plain English?

Comment: @UmbertoP. It's the boundary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intuitively, the closure $\overline{M}$ of a set $M$ comprises (1) points that are in the set to begin with, and (2) points that are not in the set but are really really close to the set.

In particular, a point of $x$ of type (2) above has the property that if you form a open ball centered at that point, it will contain some other point from the set $M$ -- no matter how small the ball is.

- So the open ball of radius $1$ centered at $x$, denoted $B(x,1)$, contains a point $x_1\in M$.
- And the open ball of radius $\frac12$ centered at $x$, denoted $B(x,\frac12)$, contains a point $x_2\in M$.
- And the open ball $B(x,\frac13)$ contains a point $x_3\in M$.
- And so on; for each $n=1, 2, 3, \ldots,$ each ball $B(x,\frac1n)$ contains a point $x_n\in M$.

These balls are nested, so $B(x,\frac1n)$ contains $x_k$ for all $k\geq n$. This is practically the definition of $x_n\to x$. So we have constructed a sequence of points $x_n$ in $M$ with $x_n\to x$.

For points $x$ of type (1) above, you already have $x\in M$, so you can just take $x_n=x$ for all $n$ (constant sequence), so of course $x_n\to x$.